# T-SQL Get Counter for # of Open Quotes in Date Range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, date-range

I'm trying to figure out how many 'Open Quotes' there were in each month/year and not sure how to do this automatically.  I don't want to have to manually enter time ranges to do this and looking for help.

I've uploaded a sample CSV file and data here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1N1kwbFUtOUpMa2c

The first two rows from the tables look like this:

tbl_QuoteWin

```
Quote_No    Add_Date    Update_Date     Quote_Status
5           05-Aug-15       10-15-Oct           Win
6           17-Sep-15       18-15-Nov           Win
```

tbl_QuoteOpen

```
Quote_No    Add_Date      Update_Date        Quote_Status
1           08-Aug-15                               Open
3           07-Sep-15                               Open
```

tbl_QuoteLoss

```
Quote_No    Add_Date         Update_Date     Quote_Status
2           07-Aug-15         17-Oct-15             Loss
4           25-Sep-15         7-Nov-15              Loss
```

The desired output is a way for me to divide how many quotes we won in a month by how many quotes were open in a month.  I don't know how to capture the months between 'Add_Date_Month' and 'Update_Date_Month'.

For example, in tbl_QuoteWin, quote #2 should be in the count of 'Open' quotes for Aug-2015 and Sept-2015 because this quote was in an 'Open' status before it was put in a 'Win' status in Oct-2015.

I originally tried to pull out just the month/year and then thought I might be able to do something with that but I really don't know how to tackle this problem.  Even if I did a DATEDIFF() I'd get a length of time, not the actual months.

I hope this makes sense and thank you in advance for helping me or at least pointing me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: are your date columns stored as dates or strings?

Comment: I am not sure about the flow. In your data quote #2 is both in loss and win for update 15.oct?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of quotes opened in a specific month, or the total count of open quotes in the month? If a quote is lost and won in a onth, should it be counted as the open quotes in the month or not?
Perhaps if you could add a desired output to your question this could help the understanding

Comment: @SørenKongstad, Corrected sample data.  I want the total count of open quotes in each month.  If a quote closes (Win/Loss) in a month it should not be counted as 'Open' in that month.  So if a quote is opened in Jan/2015 and won in June/2015, in the historical data it should count as 'Open' in Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May and 'Won' in June.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTH(Add_Date),YEAR(Add_Date), COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_QUOTEOpen 
GROUP BY MONTH(Add_Date),YEAR(Add_Date)
```

This solution is possible because only quotes with an open status are in the Open Quote table.  Once they are won or lost, they move to another table.
The results, based on the tables in your question, would be

```
8  2015 1
9  2015 1
```